# Building a timeseries dataset from an API using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api, time-series, plotly-dash

I am building a dataset, ultimately to be used to make an interactive online data visualization app with Dash.

This is my first project with Python (and programming in general), and I am trying to decide how best to go about retrieving, storing and updating the data for the dataset.

This is the api I am using:
https://covid19api.com/

documentation:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest

I have written some code that pulls down the data I need on a per country basis and manipulates it to create series' that I need

```
# Import the libraries
import requests

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from pandas import json_normalize

from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/ireland'
data = requests.get(url)

# Store the API response in a variable.
available_data = data.json()
df_ire = json_normalize(available_data)

# rename the date to datetime
df_ire = df_ire.rename(columns={"Date" : "datetime"})

#convert the data to datetime format
df_ire["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df_ire["datetime"])

# Create Daily new cases column & SMA
df_ire["New Cases"] = df_ire['Confirmed'].diff()
df_ire["SMA_10 New Cases"] = df_ire["New Cases"].rolling(window=10).mean()

# Create Daily new deaths column & SMA
df_ire["New Deaths"] = df_ire['Deaths'].diff()
df_ire["SMA_10 New Deaths"] = df_ire["New Deaths"].rolling(window=10).mean()

df_ire.fillna(0)

#set datetime as index
df_ire.set_index('datetime')

#Plot New Cases
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
plt.grid(False)
plt.plot(df_ire["SMA_10 New Cases"], label="New Cases - 10-Day Moving Average", 
         color = "orange", linewidth = 4 )
ax.bar(df_ire.index, df_ire["New Cases"], label = "Daily New Confirmed Cases")

ax.set(xlabel='Days Since First Confirmed Case', ylabel='Number of Infections',
       title='Ireland: Average vs Daily New Cases')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.legend(loc=2);

plt.savefig('ireland_avg_vs_daily_cases', dpi = 1067, bbox_inches='tight' )
```

As of right now I am just working with data for one country and using matplotlib as I figure out best how to present and process the data. Here is an example of what I have done so far: [image: chart]

The finished project should look something like this, but with rates of change on all countries:
https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-opioid-epidemic/

First of all, the API is a community project and in development and I don't want to overload their system with requests, so I am trying to structure my project so as to minimize the amount of load that I put on their system. I'm - quite simply - not aware of what good/bad practices are with regards using apis, and I don't want to be "that guy".

As I said above, I also need to think about storing the data and updating it at appropriate intervals. It is time series data for 248 countries, and recording several variables, all of which will need to be manipulated in pandas and appended to regularly. Should I build one massive dataframe? Should I build a dataframe for each country, each variable?

Once I have created the dataset, I am hoping to update & append it using similar code to what I have above, using this api call:
https://api.covid19api.com/summary

Is that a good plan and what should it look like?

My plan is to host on Heroku (or something similar), when it is finished.

Thank you very much if you are still reading at this point. I know this is a very long-winded post, and I am asking a lot of questions in one go. I have been trying to think about how to proceed with this all afternoon, and I know that I need to make some fundamental decisions in order to proceed. Any help at all would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Since you are already using requests, you can use ```requests-cache``` to limit how often you hit the external API.

Comment: Cool. I was not aware of this. I'm just looking into some documentation now. Thank you!

Comment: This actually looks to solve my main problem straight away. Amazing!